# Validation using preg_match functions

Tags: php, validation

I need some improvements on my code. I did some validation by `preg_match` and functions.  I need some special characters restrictions every field.

```
<?php
$error='';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
if(nameField($_POST['name'])=='')
{
    $error="Invalid Name";
}

if(numberField($_POST['phone'])=='')
{
    $error.="<br>Invalid Number";
}
if(nameField($_POST['address'])=='')
{
    $error.="Invalid Address";
}
if($error)
{
    echo $error;
}
else
{
    echo "Form submitted successfully";
}
}

function nameField($val)
{
if(preg_match("/([%\$#\*\'\"\()]+)/", $val)) //Not allowed some of the special characters
{
return false;
}
else
{
return true;
}
}
function numberField($val)
{
if(preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/", $val))
{
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="text" name="phone">
<input type="text" name="address">
<input type="text" name="city">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to keep things brief, for a change:

`nameField` seems reasonable enough. Although I do have some suggestions (see below).
The `numberField` function is another matter. If you want to check for a valid phone number, there are a couple of things to consider:

- User tend to enter a phone number in a human-readable format: *213-1234-4454* or *123/1234.4567*
- International phone numbers can start with *Either* a double `0`, or a plus sign. both of which are valid: *(0012) 123/1234-5678* is a possible value you'd have to process, just as *+12 123/1234-5678*

Bottom line: First trim the non-numeric chars, then check if the input is valid, I'd say:

```
function sanitizeAndValidate($phoneNr)
{
    //replace all non-numeric chars, after replacing a single + char with 00
    $phone = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', str_replace('+', '00', $phone, 1));
    $len = strlen($phone);
    //perhaps changing these constants to argumenst might be preferable
    if (is_numeric($phone) && $len >= MIN_PHONE_LEN && $len <= MAX_PHONE_LEN)
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
            sprintf(
                '%s is an invalid phone number (%s after sanitation)',
                $phoneNr,
                $phone
            )
        );
    return $phone;

}
```

Pas the raw phone number to this function, if the phone number is valid, you'll get a santized version back. If the phone number is invalid, catch the exception and present the user with an error message.

The `nameField` function is OK, but it's a bit redundant. If you only use it in one place, I'd avoid the overhead of a function-call, and simply inline the check, by replacing `if (nameField($_POST['name']))` with this:

```
if (preg_match('/([%_\$#*\'"\()]+)/', $_POST['name']))
```

You might have noticed that I don't escape all of the chars, simply because there's no reason to escape them all. I've also added `_` to the restricted chars. Simply because everybody knows that `%` is a MySQL wildcard, but not everybody seems to be aware that `_` is, too.

Regular expressions can impact preformance, which is, I suspect, why you're asking for ways to improve your code. An alternative to `preg_match` here could be to have an array of prohibited chars, and use `str_replace`:

```
$notAllowed = array('%', '_', '$', '#', ...);//and so on
if (str_replace($notAllowed, '', $_POST['name']) !== $_POST['name'])
{//values are not the same, a forbidden char was replaced
    //name contains prohibited char
}
```

I'm not so sure if that would be faster then a `preg_match`, though, and besides: premature optimization is the root of all evil.

*Last comment:*
Please, try to adhere to [the coding standards](http://www.php-fig.org) as much as possible. You seem to have some formatting issues

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The nameField() I've to use more times and other pages also.

Comment: @Prakash: In that case, keep the function, but make sure that `str_replace` isn't the faster option. Also simplify it a bit: write `function nameField($n) { return preg_match('/<your regex>/', $n); }` instead of the `if-else` business. It'll return what illegal char was found, which could be useful

Answer (score 2):

- Please, please, *please* indent your code.
- HTML5 includes `<input type="tel" />` for phone numbers, though it's currently unsupported by the major browsers. You can choose whether or not you want to use this; it'll just default to a `text` field.
- There is no point in using `if (condition) return true; else return false;`. Ever. Instead, just write:

  ```
  return preg_match('/^[0-9]*$/');
  ```
- You could name `numberField` better; the function name should include a verb. Furthermore, do you really mean to match empty string? If not, use `+` instead of `*`.
- Your use of `$error` is inconsistent. I propose using an array instead:

  ```
  $errors = array();
  if (nameField...) {
      $errors[] = "Invalid Name";
  }
  if (numberField...) {
      $errors[] = "Invalid Number";
  }
  ...
  echo $errors ? implode("<br />", errors) : "Form submitted successfully";
  ```